# lambda fct returning reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have tried hard to make a lambda function return a value by reference *without* making a copy of the referenced value. 
My code example below illustrates the problem. It compiles and runs ok, but with the "//" commented line instead of the line above, it doesn't.
I have found two workarounds (both illustrated in my example):

- wrap the result with std::ref()
- return a pointer instead of a reference

But both workarounds are not what I really want, and I do not understand why they are necessary: The expression "makeRefA()" has already the type the lambda function returns (const A&) and thus must neither be copied nor converted. By the way: The copy constructor is *really* called when I do not explicitly delete it (which in my "real" code is a performance problem).
To me it looks like a compiler bug, but I have tried with several C++11-compilers which all show up the same error. So is there something special concerning the "return" statement in a lambda function?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A(int i) : m(i) { }
  A(const A&) = delete;
  int m;
};

void foo(const A & a) {
  std::cout << a.m <<'\n';
}

const A & makeRefA() {
  static A a(3);
  return a;
}

int main() {
  std::function<const A&()> fctRef = [&]
    { return std::ref(makeRefA()); }; //compiles ok
    //{ return makeRefA(); }; //error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)'
  foo(fctRef());

  std::function<const A*()> fctPtr = 
    [&] { return &makeRefA(); };
  foo(*fctPtr());

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
3
3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the automatically-deduced type of a lambda is the non-reference version of a type

> ... the return type is the type of the returned expression (after lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer implicit conversion);  [(source)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

If you want a return type with a reference, you will have to specify it more explictly. Here are some options:

```
[&]()
-> decltype( makeRefA() )
{ return makeRefA()); };
```

or simply be fully explicit about the return type with `->`

```
[&]()
-> const A&
{ return makeRefA(); }
```

If using C++14, then simply use `decltype(auto)`,

```
[&]()
-> decltype(auto)
{ return makeRefA(); }
```

The rules for `decltype` can be complicated at times. But the fact that `makeRefA()` is an expression (as opposed to simply naming a variable) means that the type of the expression (`const A&`) is faithfully returned by `decltype( makeRefA() )`.

Comment: "It will return a reference when the expression type is a reference" <-- Correct-ish. The expression *type* will never be a reference, but you'll get the right answer if you think about it that way.

Comment: It works even without the extra brackets, i.e. std::function<const A&()> fctRef = [&] ()->decltype( makeRefA() ) { return makeRefA(); };

Comment: Good point about the fact the extra brackets aren't necessary, @Stefan. In fact, I think I'll just remove them from the question as they might be unhelpful in other code

Answer (score 7):

You can specify the return type

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A(int i) : m(i) { }
    A(const A&) = delete;
    int m;
};

void foo(const A & a) {
    std::cout << a.m <<'\n';
}

const A & makeRefA() {
    static A a(3);
    return a;
}

int main() {
    std::function<const A&()> fctRef = [&]()->const A&
//    { return std::ref(makeRefA()); }; //compiles ok
    { return makeRefA(); }; // works
    foo(fctRef());

    std::function<const A*()> fctPtr =
    [&] { return &makeRefA(); };
    foo(*fctPtr());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow somehow totally breezed past the static part :/

Comment: Ok thanks, that's another workaround, but why is this necessary for a function returning "const A&", whereas for a function returning "const A*" it is not?

Comment: @stefan: it's not a "workaround". Under some circumstances you're allowed to leave out the return type of a lambda function. This is not one of those circumstances. It's the same reason that `auto a = b` does not make `a` a reference to `b`.

Comment: @rici ok, that almost explains it to me! But what are the "circumstances" where I must explicitly specify the lambda function's return type? To me this looks like a common "pitfall" - it seems that the compiler guesses the result, so why does it not simply guess exactly the type the function "return"s?

Comment: @Stefan: Those where automatic return type deduction fails (because, for example, there are two return statements with differently typed objects) or those where automatic return type deduction doesn't yield the type you want. Trying to return a reference falls into the second category.

Comment: @rici "> Trying to return a reference falls into the second category" But the reference is exactly the type I want, so why can't it be deduced? In other words (please compare fctPtr with fctRef): What does a "reference" have that a "pointer" doen't have?

Comment: @stefan: If references were deduced *as references* than `return id` would be deduced as a reference, because `id` has reference type, as does any lexpr. That's not generally what you want. (And, as I said earlier, it's the same reason that `auto a = b` makes `a` a copy of `b` rather than a reference to it. `auto a = makeRefA()` would also produce a copy.)

Comment: If you find the `a = b` argument insufficient, consider `auto a = v[i];` (or equivalent lambda: `[&](int size_t i){return v[i];}`.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda, these rules apply to lambdas with no trailing return type:

- In C++11, lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer implicit conversion are applied to the type of the returned expression.  (Here, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is what's hitting you.)
- In C++14 and later, the type is deduced as for a function whose return type is declared `auto`; and that in turn follows the rules for template argument deduction.  Then, since `auto` includes no reference specification, that means that references and cv-qualifiers will be ignored.

The effect is probably desirable in most situations: for example, in this lambda expression

```
[](const std::vector<int>& v) { return v[0]; }
```

you probably intend to return an `int`, even though `std::vector<int>::operator[] const` returns `const int&`.

As others have mentioned, you can override this behavior by giving an explicit trailing return type.